# Copying database from one computer to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Me and my friend both have sql server 2012. I have a database where I would like to copy over most of the tables into a database on my friends laptop. I am not sure not sure how to go about doing this?

I know in sql server that I can copy over data from one table in say database A to database B using the line below.

```
 select * into database_a.dbo.MyTable from database_a.dbo.MyTable
```

What is the best way to connect the two laptops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main options, one is to [back up the database](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/25/creating-a-backup-using-sql-server-management-studio/) and send it to your friend. To do this right click on the database, Tasks and Backup. The problem with this approach is that if you're running even slightly different versions you may have issues.

The alternative is to [script the database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/). To do this right on the database, click Tasks and Generate Scripts. Make sure you choose to script data and schema from the advanced options.

The latter is my preferred approach (as it's much more editable and human readable).

Answer (score 2):

You could take a full backup and give it to him to restore. Or you could give him a copy of the *.mdf file and let him attach it to his DB.